# Why Font is not working in Html CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have donload the Graffonti Fonts and I add the Css3 but html result not shown the font.

My Css File Has this code,..

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: Graffonti;
        src: url('fonts/Graffonti/graffonti.3d.drop.[fontvir.us].ttf');
    }

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    margin-bottom: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-family: 'Graffonti',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Font is in fonts/Graffont folder,. Is I want to install font in my system ?

What is the mistake?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally have multiple versions of the font to allow for multiple browsers if you go here and upload your font, it generates the code and font formats for you :
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: I have only ttf file. The what I do?

Answer (score 1):

Is the fonts/ folder in the same directory as the css file?

```
[fonts] [images] index.html style.css
```

If the fonts folder is accessible via `http://domain.com/fonts/Graffonti/.../graffonti...ttf`
then change the url to include a root slash `/fonts/`

I also recommend removing the brackets [] from the font file name and updating the code to match.

`src:url('/fonts/Graffonti/graffonti.3d.drop.fontvir.us.ttf');`

Answer (score 0):

Don't Forgot the Coding..

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

This Coding May Help,.. Its Support Below Browsers.

> Safari 5.03, IE 6-9, Firefox 3.6-4, Chrome 8, iOS 3.2-4.2, Android
>   2.2-2.3, Opera 11